# Ajax call with Laravel 5 returns Error 500 (Internal Server Error), even when csrf token is passed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

The title say's it all.

**.blade.php file:**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

            <article class="post" data-postid=" {{ $post->id }} ">
                <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                <div class="info"> 
                    Posted by {{$post->user->first_name}}  on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>
                <div class="interaction">
                    <a href="#" class="like">Like</a> |
                    <a href="#" class="like">Dislike</a>
                    @if(Auth::user() == $post->user) 
                        |
                        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a> 
                    @endif
                </div>
            </article>

        @endforeach
```

**JS within .blade.php file:**

```
<script>
        var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
        var urlEdit = '{{ route('edit') }}';
        var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}';
    </script>
```

**.js file:**

```
 $('.like').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null; //Checks if it's a like or dislike.

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token}
    })
    .done(function(){

    });
});
```

- I've tried to check if I did something wrong with the route.
- I tried passing the token inside a meta-tag instead of defining it as a javascript variable
- I tried using double bracelets " instead of single ones '.

Nothing seems to work, what's going on here?

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting on? If not, add it and take a look at the error returned, itll tell you a lot more than we could guess. Let us know what that says and we can help more

Comment: Well I have error reporting on from what I know of, so it shouldn't be anything with the PHP. 

Anyway, I "solved" it by excluding csrf-verification in the "App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken" simply by adding the path within 
`protected $except = [
        '/path'
    ];`

Comment: *Error 500 (Internal Server Error)* pretty specifically means that there was an error on the server and that error is almost certainly thrown in the php. Anyway, happy you got it worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add meta with csrf like this.

```
<head>
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>

<script>
  $('.like').bind('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
  var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null; 
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {isLike: isLike, postId: postId, _token: token},
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(){
          $('#loading').show();
        },          
       success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: please check this and let me know